# mysql database SQL syntax error php

Tags: php, mysql, syntax

I get the message:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax;check the manual that corresponds 
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
'12:00,25.32,1015.19,42.32,200.0,1.29,2.25,7.11,11.58,5.97,3.5,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,37'
at line 2
```

relevant code:

```
$con = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1", "username", "password") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("database",$con) or die (mysql_error());

//readFmi() returns an array of strings with values separated by commas
$array =  readFmi($xml);

$cols = 'date, Temperature, Pressure, Humidity, WindDirection, WindSpeedMS,
MaximumWind, WindGust, DewPoint, TotalCloudCover, LowCloudCover, MediumCloudCover,
HighCloudCover, Precipitation1h, PrecipitationAmount, RadiationLW, RadiationGlobal,
RadiationNetTopAtmLW';

foreach($array as $a){
  $a2 = mysql_real_escape_string($a);
  echo $a2."<br>";
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO forecastsFMI ($cols)
  VALUES ($a2)") or die (mysql_error());
}

mysql_close($con);
```

$a when printed looks like this

```
2013-06-24 12:00,25.32,1015.19,42.32,200.0,1.29,2.25,7.11,11.58,5.97,3.5,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,375.85,550.09,-260.6
```

$cols are the exact same ones as found in the table in the database, I set them all to be varchar for now, while trying to figure out where i have made my mistake(s). I have been counting the fields in the db and values to see if that is where i have gone wrong, tried to change the format of the string itself and tried to change and tweak different parts of the code, without any difference in result. What might cause this?

Thank you 
//Tobias

Comment: Look at the very first thing in the error message. It says `12:00`. There are no quotes around it, and 12:00 is not a format valid for a decimal.

Comment: Put them as strings. In other words - quote the $a2 variable

Comment: You might also be better off quoting the column names with backticks, too - date is a reserved word in mysql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add quotes around string/date column values in string. So in you case specially you need something like.

```
"2013-06-24 12:00",25.32,1015.19,42.32,200.0,1.29,2.25,7.11,11.58,5.97,3.5,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,375.85,550.09,-260.6
```